# How to share owin token from .Net Framework with .Net Core 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, owin

I have a .Net Framework application which is already in production that uses owin oauth to authenticate users, I have built a .Net core 6 application which uses the same database but I want to add auth to it, I was wondering how would I share the access token from my .Net Framework application to my .Net core 6 application. My .Net framework makes use of OWIN authentication and we get a cookie back as well as an access token, how would I use the same items on .Net core 6, I have tried making a simple Identity Authentication on my .Net core 6 application but that changes the password hash on the the ASPNetUsers table and then I cant login from my .Net Framework application anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, asp.net core also support OWIN authentication, you could use the oauth's settings inside the asp.net core application. For example, both the Asp.net and asp.net core support the JWT authentication, if the token's issuer and secect or other settings is the same, we could use access token.